# How to access/edit flutter premade widgets like Text/FlatButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to see the code inside the FlatButton on flutter. How can I view its source code?
what is the keyboard shortcut for in android studio?

Comment: Control Click on the object on windows and command Click on Mac

Comment: you basically want the code declaration : Main menu | Navigate | Declaration

Comment: Thanks it worked :)